# i have a legacy webspere soap web service to be migrated to tomcat

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, tomcat8

i have a legacy webspere soap web service provider to be migrated to tomcat.
soap service is using IBM native libraries, any suggestions? can i reuse the existing wsdl file from this project? and what is the best approach to achieve this? considering consumer should'nt make any code changes other than the service url.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this without changing anything would be to move your war file to Tomcat. Identify the native jars that are being used. Place these jars in tomcat's lib. This approach requires minimal code change.

WSDL files are not technology specific and you can reuse it. You can even re create the web service skeleton using the WSDL file but that would still mean writing the code for Business logic. See if this is what you want :-

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Creating_a_Top-Down_Java_Web_Service_Skeleton_from_a_WSDL_Document